# What kind of library is dos.h (static or dynamic)?

Tags: c++, c, dynamic, static, libraries

I am working on a project for my University. One of the points is that we are not allowed to use non-static libraries. As I am dealing with interrupts I would like to use dos.h to avoid complicating things with assembly (setvect() instead of bunch of assembly line codes).

The rough translation of the part considering usage of libraries is:
"... it is allowed to use only standard (static) C/C++ libraries which are independent of the platform (hardware and OS). It is NOT allowed to use specific libraries of the system-host or dynamic libraries (DLL)"

Can someone please tell me what kind of library is dos.h?

Comment: The name "dos.h" implies a relationship with "DOS", which is pretty specific to an OS! This is only an implication, though: I don't know what this header is and you provide no context. What is `dos.h`? Which `dos.h` are you using? Where did you get it from? I can make you a file named `dos.h` right now that'll be completely platform independent (though it almost certainly won't do the same thing as the `dos.h` file you already have).

Comment: "which are independent of the platform (hardware and OS)" <- Well, `dos.h` is most certainly dependent on the platform (OS).

Comment: Thanks. I thought it wasn't independent but I wasn't sure so I asked. Seems I'll have to do this the hard way.

@DanielFischer If you'll post it as an answer I would except it.

Once again thanks for the answers. [:

Comment: Kind of a bizarre set of rules. It's impossible to run a process on Windows, say, without using a DLL. For instance, every process starts with kernel32.dll already loaded. I think you need to seek clarification on what those rules really mean.

Comment: I am create my own OS so that may clarify some things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A header file `*.h` is not a library it is just a set of definitions and declarations.

If the assignment truly asks you to **both** use hardware interrupts **and** be OS independent then it is inconsistent because different operating systems define how hardware interrupts are handled differentlty.

I suspect you are misunderstanding the assignment and should ask your instructor for clarification.

**added in response to comment**

Yes, writing a tiny OS does mostly explain the inconsistency. As noted above, kernel32.dll likely provides some of the services (e.g. `setvect()`) which you want to make use of. If there is no OS, then there are no OS services to rely on and you will have to write your own (which I imagine is part of the purpose of the assignment).

Comment: I know headers are a set of definitions and declarations but when I include, lets say iostream.h I am indirectly including the iostream library?

Also, the task is to create a small but operating kernel. That could be the answer to inconsistency? I am not sure.

I think I understood most of the task I was given. And even if I wasn't I would have to find my own way. There are no instructors where I am from and professors don't have the time.

Comment: @InvaderZim - see **added** above

Comment: In these circumstances, you can only rely on the headers that need to be present for a _Freestanding Implementation_. This is a specific term in C++, and means what you roughly describe - no OS support etc. In particular, neither `<iostream>` nor `"dos.h"` are officially part of a freestanding implementation.